# Android UI Implementation Advice Needed

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm fairly new to Android and I'm working on an application in which one particular section involves a more advanced UI interface than what you would normally create with the stock UI components.  I've read through most of the SDK tutorials and I get the basics but I can't see how to implement something like this.  I'm not looking for any code, just some advice on what technologies I should be reading about to achieve this.

Here is a mockup:

[image: app mockup]

So basically at the top there is a thumbnail strip that the user can flip through. Clicking on a thumbnail will perform some action.  I'm pretty sure there's a stock control for this.

Underneath that I need to be able to create a composite image that can be pinch zoomed and panned and has hotspots that can be clicked (tapped) on.  For example, an image of the solar system, in which the background would be static, but the planets need to be placed at runtime and need to be clickable, and the whole thing needs to be pan/zoomable.  Support for very minimal animation (eg slow planet rotation) would be a plus, but not necessary. I'm at a loss on what I would achieve this with.

Finally, there are three pull-out panes that contain other content, such as images, menu items, and other media.  Basically these just need to be containers in which I can place  any other UI content.

I've done some basic Activities so far with simple forms, so I understand the basic workflow of Android, but I'm just not sure what to look at to achieve something like this. Is this a good candidate for a SurfaceView?  Is there something else I should look at?  I have been a bit afraid to get involved with OpenGL, since I don't really have a 3D background, and I still want to be able to use native components (buttons, listboxes, etc) without having to re-implement them in OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this for the slides:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

as for the thumbnails you can use a linear layout, with some imageviews and buttons.

Comment: That code is for transitioning an entire screen,  what I'm looking for with the slide-out panels is to not leave the screen.  They would function like a drawer.